# Difference between PHP expression return value and variable

Tags: php

Why does it make a difference if a function's return value (a variable) is passed and not a variable directly?
In the [PHP documentation for the empty() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) it is stated that

> 5.5.0: empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.

But why would that make a difference anyway?
If the given expression has a variable as a return value - in my eyes - both statements would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.5, the returned value is a **value**, not a variable because when you say

```
return $value;
```

in your called function, $value is only valid in the scope of the function; it ceases to exist as a variable as soon as the function terminates its execution, so the calling code only receives the value

Comment: Guess I've mixed up values and variables. Kind of confusing... Thanks though!

Comment: @pudelhund `empty` is a language construct, not a function. The difference is that is doesn't play by a function's rules (it isn't required to accept values from other functions as input, etc). Prior to PHP 5.5, it worked _directly on the variables_ without trying to get a value out of them first. That behavior has now changed to allow additional functionality, but I just want to clarify that `empty` is not a special kind of function or anything, it's just _not a function_ at all. This is the same with `isset`, `echo`, `print`, `die`, and `exit`

Comment: Wow, that's good to know! Is there a list with all the PHP language constructs?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php is a list of the reserved words, most of which are language constructs (excepting the constants)